# Driving 4x6 into marsh by hand

Tags: fence

I'm building a marsh boardwalk behind my house. The marsh varies from muddy to perhaps 2 feet of water. I've trying to sink 4x6 posts for the main supports, but it's proving to be very difficult with a sledge. I believe I'll need to sink these at least 4 feet, and I've only managed perhaps 2.5 after 30+ minutes of hitting it with a sledge.

I can't seem to find a post driver that fits 4x6 posts. Most are meant for metal stakes or, at best, 2x4s.

I've seen some people recommend using a water jet to "dig" below the post, bur before I buy a $250 water pump, does anybody know of another, cheaper alternative?

Comment: Wooden posts will have a limited life.  I recently had to replace all the wooden supports for a dock because they had rotted away.  The longer-term solution is to use metal pipe.  Plus, it's pretty easy to drive in with a post driver.

Comment: Have you tried a pressure washer as a jet?

Comment: Did you try cutting a point on the end of the 4x6? I would think that a 30 degree point would drive a lot easier than a flat bottom timber.

Comment: Timbers that large are almost never driven into soil by hand. Their large cross-section makes it more difficult than a person using human strength or bodyweight can accomplish.

Comment: Combining comments , jet in pipes , forget the 4 X 6. I have jetted 2 " pipe with city water pressure in a garden hose ( about 6 ' ) and one inch copper pipe to 10 ' ( ground rod).

Comment: 4 x 6 is fine, jetting is the answer; and yes you should chisel point the piles and twist them as they go in, to cut roots.

Comment: Perhaps 4x6 is overkill? Should I try 4x4 instead? My previous attempt did have the bottom cut to a point.

Comment: FWIW, I ended up using these and they work great: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0754CJHJ4/

Answer (score 3):

So driving these posts into the marsh was essentially impossible by hand. 4x4's might have worked, but even that would have been extremely difficult.

I ended up buying [helical screw piles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0754CJHJ4) and these worked great. Still a ton of work, but all it took was some leverage with a long 2x4 to get them in.

Comment: please accept your answer this way folks and the system realize your question has a solution that works.